# Split string as per the text AND , NOT?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string like below:

```
var  str ='video AND music NOT movie AND moble NOT laptop';
```

Above string split after AND and NOT and store in 2 different arrays.

After AND text in different array.

After NOT text different array dynamically.

Output looks like

`["video","music","mobile"],["movie","laptop"]`

Comment: can you be more clear? May be an example

Comment: var str ='video AND music NOT movie AND moble NOT laptop';

Comment: and what should be the result?

Comment: I want split string after AND, NOT word.   And store in two different array.

Comment: Edit your question and add examples of what the arrays should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function haveAndNots(str) {
  var nots = [];
  str = str.replace(/NOT (\w+)/g, function(m, c) {
    nots.push(c);
    return '';
  });

  return {
    have: str.split('AND').map(str => str.trim()),
    nots: nots
  }
}

var str = 'video AND music NOT movie AND mobile NOT laptop';
var split = haveAndNots(str);
console.log(split.have);
console.log(split.nots);
```

Comment: This is more elegant than mine

Answer (score -1):

Use split function.

```js
var str = 'video AND music NOT movie AND moble NOT laptop';
var strAnd = [];
var strNot = [];
var temp = str.split(' ');
$.each(temp, function(key, value) {
  if (value === 'AND') {
    strAnd.push(temp[key + 1])
  } else if (value === 'NOT') {
    strNot.push(temp[key + 1])
  }
});
console.log(strAnd,strNot);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```